# Read wma and edit id3 tags

Tags: music, music-player, id3, wma

Using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

I've been trying to edit the id3 tags of my wma music files. Since many of these files are in the folder "unknown album (random date)" in "unknown artist", it would be best if I could listen to the songs in the same place, so I can identify them. These are the software I tried:

rhythmbox: can't even find my wma files. Installing gstreamer1.0-plugins-good and gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly didn't fix the issue.
audacious: reads the wma files, doesn't let me edit their id3 tags
lollypop: I can't for the life of me figure out how to access *any* id3 tags. Googling didn't help.
SMPlayer: at least I can access the id3 tags? But it's not a music library manager, so I don't really expect to be able to edit the id3 tags anyway (yes, at that point I was just downloading random music players)
Sayonara: I can edit the wma id3 tags! Success! But it's complaining that it's missing codecs for reading them. After some research, these seem to be the codes I already installed.

Anyway, I'm getting tired of installing one random music player after the other, can someone help?

ETA: line breaks

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose the right tool for each job. For playing the audio (to find out what the tracks are) I'd use VLC, but for tagging, I'd recommend EasyTag. https://help.gnome.org/users/easytag/stable/

Both are available in the Ubuntu Archive.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Unfortunately, it seems that easytag can't read wma files.

Comment: Another option is kid3, which claims to be able to read wma files.

Comment: thanks, kid3 works!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone lands here, turns out Clementine can do both. But it also turns out that using a dedicated tool like kid3 is more practical.